# IE conditional comments appear in view page

Tags: comments, conditional-statements

my conditional comments appear as part of my rendered page. I have placed everything in the right place. The conditional comments appear when I test my project in IE9, 8, and 7.

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<h:outputScript name="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"/>
<h:outputScript name="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"/>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

you comment should be in this way..

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]-->    <!--[endif]-->
```